# EF Core Skip(x).Take(x) ломает Include

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Есть код

```
var query = this._context.Bottle
                .Where(u => u.CreatedUserId == userId);

query = query.Include(b => b.Recipe).ThenInclude(r => r.RecipeAromas).ThenInclude(r => r.Aroma).ThenInclude(r => r.Vendor);

query = query.Skip(gridParams.PageSize * gridParams.Page).Take(gridParams.PageSize);
```

Но не все Recipe инклудяться, если убрать  Skip(x).Take(x) - все работает как положенно.
Никто не знает как исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Это EF7? Попробуйте порядок поменять:

```
var query = this._context.Bottle.Include(b => b.Recipe).ThenInclude(r => r.RecipeAromas).ThenInclude(r => r.Aroma).ThenInclude(r => r.Vendor);               

query =  query.Where(u => u.CreatedUserId == userId).Skip(gridParams.PageSize * gridParams.Page).Take(gridParams.PageSize);
```